# Is this the right expression when I first meet someone?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

I am making a video which explains my business. In my video, I would like to say "hello" to someone who watches my video.
Is it rude to say "hi, there"?
If this is a rude or an unsuitable expression, what is the right expression in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing rude about "Hi, there," but you'll want to say it with the right tone and mood, or it may come across as very insincere.

If I wanted to use "Hi, there!" as an introduction to my video, I'd say it as if the viewer had just come up to me from behind, and I turned around to see them approaching.

I don't think there's a single "right expression" for this situation. It's probably most important for your greeting to sound warm, friendly, sincere and unrehearsed.

Answer (score 2):

While *"Hi, there!"* is not considered rude or inappropriate, it may be perceived as a bit of an odd greeting for a video presenter.  The phrase is usually used as a greeting when someone is surprised, such as walking around a corner and nearly bumping into someone you didn't expect to see - in that case, *"Oh! Hi, there!"* would be a fitting greeting.

It can also be used as a greeting to catch the attention of someone who may not initially see or notice you.  For example, it might be appropriate to call out *"Hi, there!"* as a greeting to a preoccupied store clerk from whom you would like to get some help.  In a slight variation of this, it might also be used by an adult to greet a shy child hiding behind their mother's skirt - one might say *"Hi, there!"* with a warm smile to try to coax a response from the bashful youngster.

If, in your video, the presenter is surprised by the approach or presence of the camera, then *"Hi, there!"* would be an appropriate greeting.  But it would also probably come off as a bit cheesy.  A more appropriate introduction might be to have the presenter pose a thought-provoking question or do something to briefly introduce the subject of the video, and then simply introduce themselves and give a synopsis of what is to follow.  A greeting of *"Hello, my name is..."* or *"Hi, I'm ..."* would also be appropriate for a video introduction.

Comment: In regards to your first paragraph- I actually think this type of greeting in a video is cliche, not unusual as you suggested. It's the old *Oh, hello, I didn't see you there.* I still wouldn't recommend it though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe originally "**hi**" (as well as "**hello**") started as an exclamation to draw attention to oneself from another person or persons.  If you omit "*there*", it will sound just a bit more "official" albeit still not formal (if that's what you shoot for).

Nowadays "*hello*" is mostly used as a greeting.

There are other ways, of course, of starting a video presentation.  You could always say, "*Welcome to my presentation*!", or do it after a "*Hello*!".

Another way to start a presentation is, "*Greetings*!"

Comment: I would advise against "Greetings"; it will just sound odd.

Comment: In this situation, I think "Hello" fits best as a somewhat formal greeting, respectful but not overly stiff nor too casual.

Comment: Good Morning/ afternoon/evening

Comment: I'm from the Southern US, so I'd likely say "Howdy folks". I'm on the fence about whether a video should address the entire audience, or just one viewer. It would depend on the type if video.

Comment: @Mrstupid - The problem with a video greeting like "Good morning" or "Good evening" is you may have no control over when the video gets watched. For example, "Good afternoon" might sound a little odd at 8 in the morning.

Answer (score -2):

It is quite impersonal. Don't you know the person's name? I find it offensive, personally, if someone knows me. Maybe they forgot my name, but if they know me I really prefer they use my name. Are they trying to give me the cold shoulder by saying hi "there"? It does raise that question. People are not "theres". It's almost dismissive.